# Python asyncore & dbus

Tags: python, dbus, asyncore

Is it possible to integrate `asyncore` with `dbus` through the same `main loop`?

Usually, DBus integration is done through `glib` main loop: is it possible to have either `asyncore` integrate this main loop *or* have dbus use `asyncore`'s ?

Comment: Why would you use asyncore when you have glib? glib seems much more capable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`asyncore` sucks. `glib` already provides async stuff, so just use `glib`'s mainloop to do everything.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a trivial [`GSource`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-new) wrapper for one of [my own projects](http://code.google.com/u/anacrolix/) called [`AsyncoreGSource`](http://code.google.com/p/lanshare/source/browse/lanshare-gtk.py?spec=svn1d438e64437f3d8039473846a3b9613d183ba3dc&r=1d438e64437f3d8039473846a3b9613d183ba3dc#16)

Just [attach](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-attach) it to an appropriate [`MainContext`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainContext):

```
source = AsyncoreGSource([socket_map])
source.attach([main_context])
```

Naturally the defaults are `asyncore.socket_map` and the [default `MainContext`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-default) respectively.

You can also try [monkey-patching `asyncore.socket_map`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551774-asyncoreasynchat-in-gtk/), which would have been my solution had I not poked through the [GLib python bindings source code for `GSource`](http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/glib/pygsource.c).

Comment: Note that I've since run into a few performance issues with this, and have a version that full integrates with GLib's poll interface on Linux (but not Windows). I'll update this answer when things stabilize.

Answer (score 0):

Although you got what is probably a perfectly reasonable answer, there is another approach - you don't need to use asyncore's loop per se. Just call asyncore.loop with a zero timeout and a count of 1, which stops it iterating (and thus makes the function name completely misleading) and polls the sockets just once. Call this as often as you need.

I don't know anything about glib's async support but if it requires threads you might still get better performance by using asyncore in this way since it will use select or poll and won't need to spawn additional threads.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts - I have settled on Twisted for this project.